# Excel VBA memory usage

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to copy a large number of lines (20k to 65k) into new workbooks, and for some reason, assigning the value of the range I'm copying uses more memory than using the copy/paste buffer, which doesn't make any sense to me, unless I'm somehow doing this wrong.

This is the original code:

```
Public Const FIRSTSHEETTAB As String = "Sheet1"
' <snip>

Dim last_row As Long
Dim num_files As Long
Dim ps_rng As Range
' <snip>

Dim i As Long
Dim new_book As Workbook
Dim start_row As Long
Dim end_row
start_row = 2
For i = 1 To num_files
    Set new_book = Workbooks.Add
    end_row = start_row + max_lines - 1
    If end_row > last_row Then
        end_row = last_row
    End If
    With new_book
        .Windows(1).Caption = "PS Upload " & i
        With .Worksheets(FIRSTSHEETTAB)
            .Range("1:1").Value2 = ps_rng.Range("1:1").Value2
            .Range("2:" & max_lines).Value2 = ps_rng.Range(CStr(start_row) & ":" & CStr(end_row)).Value2
        End With
    End With
    start_row = end_row + 1
Next i
```

And what I had to do to get this working was change `.Range("2:" & max_lines).Value2 = ps_rng.Range(CStr(start_row) & ":" & CStr(end_row)).Value2` to the following:

```
ps_rng.Range(CStr(start_row) & ":" & CStr(end_row)).Copy
.Range("2:" & max_lines).PasteSpecial
```

And I don't understand why this works where as the former code runs out of memory.  I'd much rather not have to overwrite whatever is in the copy/paste buffer if I can help it.

What's causing just the simple assignment to run out of memory?

Comment: Maybe you could change your code to work only with the `UsedRange` of the sheet you're copying from: that way you're not copying 16k columns of what are likely mostly empty cells. As to why it works when you do a Copy - possibly Excel is smart enough to be able to automatically exclude unused cells.

Comment: At some point in time, I realized that a Destination can be specified with [Range.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837760%28v=office.15%29.aspx).  I don't know why it didn't occur to me to just use this the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are assigning the value of 16.384 x 65.000 = 1.064.960.000 cells simultaneously and this is too much for Excel to cope with.

A better approach would be to restrict the desired range to copy using the last column that does have values. I do not recommend utilizing the UsedRange property because it does give some unwanted results sometimes when a cell far away was edited sometime ago.

Below there is a code example:

```
Public Const FIRSTSHEETTAB As String = "Sheet1"
' <snip>

Dim last_row As Long
Dim num_files As Long
Dim ps_rng As Range
' <snip>

Dim i As Long
Dim new_book As Workbook
Dim start_row As Long
Dim end_row
start_row = 2
'Obtaining last column of the desired range
lastColumn = ps_rng.Cells(1, ps_rng.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column


For i = 1 To num_files
    Set new_book = Workbooks.Add
    end_row = start_row + max_lines - 1
    If end_row > last_row Then
        end_row = last_row
    End If
    With new_book
        .Windows(1).Caption = "PS Upload " & i
        With .Worksheets(FIRSTSHEETTAB)
            .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, lastColumn)).Value2 = ps_rng.Range(ps_rng.Cells(1, 1), ps_rng.Cells(1, lastColumn)).Value2
            .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(max_lines, lastColumn)).Value2 = ps_rng.Range(ps_rng.Cells(start_row, 1), ps_rng.Cells(end_row, lastColumn)).Value2
        End With
    End With
    start_row = end_row + 1
Next i
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use `Copy`, Excel is smart enough only to copy the used part of the Copy range.

Eg. see below: granted this is looking at the "Text" version of what's on the clipboard, but that's pretty much what you're getting when you `PasteSpecial`

```
Sub Tester()

    ActiveSheet.Cells.ClearContents
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange 'reset sheet
    CheckCopy '>> 1

    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:J1").Value = "x"
    CheckCopy '>> 10

    ActiveSheet.Range("XFD1").Value = "x"
    CheckCopy '>> 16384

    ActiveSheet.Range("XFD1").ClearContents
    CheckCopy '>> 16384

    ActiveSheet.UsedRange 'reset sheet
    CheckCopy '>> 10

End Sub

Sub CheckCopy()
    Dim d As New DataObject, s As String
    ActiveSheet.Rows(1).Copy
    d.GetFromClipboard
    s = d.GetText
    Debug.Print "#Cols: " & IIf(Len(s) = 0, 0, UBound(Split(s, vbTab)) + 1)
End Sub
```

You don't get this optimization when you directly assign `Value` between two large ranges.